# YouTube API: custom button to start playing an embedded video

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, embedding, youtube-javascript-api

I have embedded a YouTube video in a website, but I want to start playing it by clicking on a custom button outside the player.

After some research on the web I've tried with this piece of js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript('http://www.youtube.com/player_api');


    $('#playvideo').click( function() {
         thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo'); thevid.style.display='block'; this.style.display='none'; $('#video').playVideo();
    });
});
```

where #playvideo is the button and #video is the YouTube iframe.

And this is the embedding html code:

```
<iframe id="video" width="266" height="150" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/uJnHiN-GsZM?rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=2&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

but it's not working on any browser and I'm receiving this JS error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'playVideo'**

anyone can give me some suggestion?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Different browsers may work slightly different...

Comment: It is not working on the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera and IE10

Comment: Just tried in jsfiddle.net Works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the video with an ID of `thevideo` here:

`document.getElementById('thevideo')`

But you later try referencing the video with an ID of `video` here:

`$('#video').playVideo();`

Make sure all of your IDs and references are correct. Then let us know if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Please try var `player = YT.Player('player'); player.playVideo();` instead